# Having a difficult time trying to use an SSD and hard disk drive at the same time in the same machine

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have a SSD already, thats how I run my PC, but I want to put a internal hard disk drive to increase storage space.

My notebook is a Lenovo IdeaPad 330, which has a data entry (where my SSD is connected) and a caddy entry that can be adapted to a sata entry through a adapter, which I did.

I got this used hard drive, a Barracuda 1TB, and I plugged into the caddy entry through the adapter I have. Now, I have an SSD and a hard disk drive plugged in, but when I turn the PC on, it either loads forever or it goes to a error blue screen.

Please, guide me on how to do it, I am very new to tech in a way, and I don't know much about how careful should I be with what things.

Here's some pics:

[image]

[image]

Please let me know if those pics are too much info

Comment: What does the blue screen say?

Comment: It's the windows error screen, but I only got it once (the first time), so I didn't take a picture or something, now it only loads forever. I can open the bios and everything seems fine, I will add some picture for you guys

Comment: So I take that you have an M.2 SSD and SATA HDD? And your laptop boots fine with SSD alone? I would check in BIOS to make sure the HDD is recognized and the SSD is still the primary drive to boot. Then check to make sure the HDD is functional. Maybe as an external harddrive.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, and it boots fine with SSD alone. I checked on bios and I think it is recognized, hence the pictures I took that shows the driver as the second hard disk. How could I check if the HDD itself is functional ? I thought about taking the SSD out to see how the HDD would do alone, but I don't know if that is the proper way. Also, I don't quite understand the "external hard drive" stuff, what does it mean ? Anyway, thank you for helping

Comment: Is the HDD functional (in another machine)? Is it recognised by the BIOS?

Comment: My friend said it was, but I don't know. The way I described (taking the SSD out and trying to run the machine with the HDD on the caddy only) would work

Comment: Does the HDD contain a bootable OS, bootloader or bootmanager?

Comment: You need to wipe the Barracuda 1TB hard drive before use. For some reason the bootable OS on the Barracuda hard drive is interfering with the SSD booting. So my recommendation is getting that drive wiped.

Comment: Your second picture shows that your laptop already HAS a SATA HDD made by Toshiba? Are you sure that it is actually possibly to use it with 2 SATA HDD's ? Some laptops have limits in regards to that.

Comment: @Tonny the Toshiba HDD is an 1TB model and most likely the one added by Gevezo. Not sure why in the question the HDD is named as "Barracuda" (did Seagate buy the Toshiba HDD company part?).

Comment: @Robert Seagate bought a part in the Toshiba NAND memory business a couple of years ago. The harddisk division is to my knowledge still fully Toshiba. And to my knowledge Seagate always changes internal disknames to properly identify the brand. Even if the disks were made on one of the production-lines they acquired from others. Besides: That Toshiba is 5400 rpm. A Barracuda (even 2.5" laptop versions) are always 7200 as far as I know. It just doesn't add up.

Comment: Yeah, after you guys talked about it it's probably a toshiba and not a barracuda, I got it written before taking the picture, and I thought it was a barracuda because it was told to me by the friend that gave it to me, so he probably messed up, and so did I.

Comment: Anyway, I plan to wipe it out now, but I'm afraid I don't know the proper way of doing this ? My plan is to take the ssd out and put only the hdd on the machine, so when I put it on I can boot and then format it. Does that sound right ?

Comment: The question should contain the transcribed error message in the body to be searchable as text.