# How to wipe out a second hand HDD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, formatting

First of all, sorry. This is going to be a very stupid question I guess, but I'm not very experienced with this.

I am currently having problems with a second hand HDD I got, you can see the complete thing on here: [Having a difficult time trying to use an SSD and hard disk drive at the same time in the same machine](https://superuser.com/questions/1656959/having-a-difficult-time-trying-to-use-an-ssd-and-hard-disk-drive-at-the-same-tim)
But I figured out that the solution to make it work is to completely wipe him out before using.

The problem is, it is a extra HDD to a notebook that already has a SSD, and whenever I plug it on the machine it does not boot.

I already have the pen driver but I'm kinda lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using the pen-drive to 'boot' from a different operating system (presumably Linux based or GParted Live) while the second hand HDD is 'plugged' to the machine.
Restart your computer

Once you have restarted your computer, wait for the first screen to appear, usually with a manufacturer's logo.
It might say “Press F2/F12/F10 to Choose Boot Device” This key might vary. The important part here is to press it and wait to continue to the next prompt. A menu with some choices should appear. Highlight USB (Pen drive) and press Return.

You could statically configure the bootable drive to appear first. Beware that everytime you start your machine with a drive included, it will boot from it. When you do not have a drive, the next choice down the list should appear.

At this point your machine should start booting on its own. Remember not to disconnect the pen drive. You might get a message like “Press any key to boot from external device,” pay attention so you do not miss it. At this point your machine should boot into the 'pen' drive instead of your second hand HD that does not have an Operating System or it is not in bootable state.

Here, you can follow the on-screen instructions to install an Operating System.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the hard drive has an OS installed on it and the laptop is trying to boot from it.  Wiping it out should fix this problem.

While your laptop is booting, hit F12 or Fn+F12 to get to the Boot Menu.  Check Lenovo's website for your model and how to get to the Boot Menu.  You should see both drives and select the one you want to boot from.  Select the SSD and it should boot normally, then allowing you to wipe the HDD.

If that doesnt work, you said you have a pen drive to use.  Download and install [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/), which allows you to write ISO images to drives.  Install it on your computer.  Then download [GParted](https://gparted.org/), which is a tool that allows you to manage partitions and format drives.  Use Etcher to write the GParted ISO to the USB stick. With the HDD installed, boot off the USB stick by selecting it in the Boot Menu.  You can then wipe the drive.

I think the easiest thing to do is get a SATA to USB adapter, like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073SXTY64).  Boot your laptop normally, then connect the HDD with the adapter.  Then you should have no problems formatting it.  For the money, a SATA to USB adapter is just a useful tool to have.